# The length of the segment cut by bisector on the side of a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, contest-math, plane-geometry

> Let ABC be a triangle, $\measuredangle$ ABC is bisected by $BE$ and $\measuredangle$ ACB is bisected by $CD$.
>   It's given that $BE = CD$.  Show that $BD = \frac{AB \cdot BC}{AC + BC}$.

A high school student asked me this question today and I was completely stumped. He goes to a magnet school in the city. The topics he went over in class were Stewart's Theorem and Ptolemy's Theorem.

For convenience let $a = BC, b = AC , c = AB$

Comment: Do you know of the angle bisector theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\dfrac{BD}{DA}=\frac{\triangle CBD}{\triangle CDA}=\frac{CB\cdot CD\sin\angle BCD}{CD\cdot CA\sin\angle DCA}=\frac{BC}{CA}=\frac ab$$
therefore
$$BD=c\cdot\frac a{a+b}$$
Q.E.D